# Concise way to create an array of differences (from an array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

Suppose I have an array of numbers and I want to create a new array that is the difference between consecutive elements. (I hope this answer to this question is generalized to other functions besides differencing!)

Is there a concise way to do this? Solutions for both regular Python implentations and Numpy/Pandas powered implentations would be appreciated!

The not-so-concise way:

```
for index in range(len(array)):
    if index < len(array) - 1:
        differences.append(array[index+1]-array[index])
```

Comment: Look into [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html).

Comment: @Divakar Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
differences = [array[index+1]-array[index] for index in range(len(array))-1]
```

This is a "list comprehension", one of the powerful features of Python.  They're more useful when they deal with the list elements directly, rather than with an index, but this example is close to your original code.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Still learning all the efficient typing that Python enables.

Comment: You might want to wait 15 minutes or so to see what others submit.  When you have a favourite, remember to "accept" it, so the question retires appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Numpy, definitely use `np.diff`. The array comprehension method, while elegant and pythonic (for python arrays) is far too slow for large-scale datasets.

In general, the rule of thumb with Numpy is: "If it's useful, or someone else would want it, it's probably in Numpy"